# MySQL: Select statement and selectively retrieve data

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp

I have a large dataset in MySQL and I would like to speed up the select statement when reading data. Assuming that there are 1000 records, I would like to issue a select statement that retrieves half of them for example but based on time-stamp.

Using something like this will not work, while id is not tightly coupled with time-stamp

```
select * from table where table.id mod 5 = 0;
```

Retrieving all the data and afterwards select the data needed is not a solution while I want to avoid retrieving the large dataset. Thus, I 'm looking for something that would distinguish the records upon select.

Thnx

Comment: you need to add indexes on the fields that in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

If you need speed then try this

```
select * from table ORDER BY table.id DESC LIMIT 0,500;

select * from table ORDER BY table.id DESC LIMIT 500,500;
```

and so on...

Comment: Using the LIMIT clause does not speed up the process while you fetch all the data (500 records). The plan is to setup a mechanism that would select the i.e. 20% of these samples in order to have a quick view and if is needed then the user will be able to get the whole 500 records (detailed view).

Comment: I gave example of limit because you said you have large dataset. You can make the limit dynamically using PHP (or any other programming language that you are using). 

first fire 

select count(id) as id_count from table

Then keep the id_count in a vaiable. To fetch 20% records you can do

$id_count=$id_count*0.2;

Then create the query
select * from table ORDER BY table.id DESC LIMIT 0,500;
the 500 should be replaced by the $id_count value.

further if you want to limit the total rows to maximum (say) 100 then you can write following code before preparing query
$id_count=min($id_count,100);